# Read JSON file?

Tags: php, json, parsing

So I wanted to search through a JSON file with PHP. The json link: http://media1.clubpenguin.com/play/en/web_service/game_configs/paper_items.json. I just put the JSON file in my webserver. Heres my script:

```
<?php
    $query = $_GET['s'];

    $terms =  explode(' ', $query);
    $results = array();

    foreach(file('items.json') as $line) {
        $found = true;

        foreach($terms as $term) {
            if(strpos($line, $term) == false) {
                $found = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if($found) {
            $results[] = $line;
        } else {

        }
    }
    print_r($results);
```

The problem is it shows the WHOLE json file instead of my $query. What can i do to fix that?

Comment: [json_decode](http://www.php.net/json_decode] Is probably what you are looking for.  Try `json_decode(file_get_contents("items.json"), true);`

Comment: Nope, just bunch of errors

Comment: What would data are you intending to search through?

Comment: @Timmy6118CP could you specify the errors?

Comment: Warning: file() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Programs\Test\index.php on line 8

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Programs\Test\index.php on line 8

Comment: PHP has a built-in function `json_decode()` that will convert a valid JSON string into a PHP array. Why don't you use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [json_encode](http://www.php.net/json_encode), [array_filter](http://www.php.net/array_filter) and a closure (PHP 5.3+) to accomplish this.

```
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://media1.clubpenguin.com/play/en/web_service/game_configs/paper_items.json"), true);

$termStr = "ninja kiwi";
$terms = explode(" ", $termStr);

$results = array_filter($obj, function ($x) use ($terms){
    foreach($terms as $term){
        if (stripos($x["label"], $term) ||
            stripos($x["paper_item_id"], $term))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
});

echo json_encode($results);
```

Comment: Thanks OrangePill! Is there any way I can change print_r to echo? I did it but i get and error: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Programs\Test\index.php on line 18

Comment: @Timmy6118CP are you trying to print json back out? if so just change `print_r($results);` to `echo json_encode($results);`

Comment: @Timmy6118CP, really? Maybe you should hire someone.

Comment: @Orangepill I tried that before. Just echos outs the json file

Comment: maybe it would help if you could show an example of what you want out of this process